# Base64decoder - PHP

Tags: php

Tenho este código abaixo, onde decodifica uma string em imagem e exibe no navegador, porem não consigo salvar a imagem decodificada com um nome randômico e salvar em disco.

```
$string  = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAgAElEQVR4nNR9d1gU1/f3mdnOLlvobelIEVEEsWPDgokaC7bYYos ........'
$decoded = base64_decode($string);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $decoded;

?>
```

Já tentei usar a função Fopen sem sucesso. Alguma dica?

Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom tente essa função, a onde  $output_file é o nome do  caminho/arquivo.png

se seu arquivo tiver um data:image/png;base64, lembre-se de da um

```
explode(",",$data) e usar o  $data[1]
```

Caso não você pode usar a função do jeito que esta aqui

```
<?php
    function base64_to_png($base64_strin) {
    $output_file = uniqid().".png";
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' ); 
    $data = $base64_string;
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data ));
    fclose( $ifp ); 
    return $output_file; 

}
?>
```

Comment: Marcos, eu apenas terei a string para ser convertida em imagem, eu ainda não teria o caminho/arquivo.png. Neste caso, eu teria que decodificar e salvar esta imagem antes? Essa é a minha dificuldade, pois eu consigo converter e mostrar a imagem na tela, mas não consigo salvar ela com algum nome qualquer.

Comment: vc que salvar a imagem  no servidor ?

Comment: Sim, após converter em imagem, queria salvar a imagem com um nome randômico e gravar em disco.

Comment: certo basta cahamar essa função que te passei  e a onde coloca o nome do arquivo coloque uniqid().".png"

Comment: isso vai gerar uma  imagem com id randonico

Comment: alterei a resposta copia a função da forma que está

Comment: Marcos, agradeço a sua ajuda/atenção. Ele está retornando erro nesta lista  fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data ); syntax error, unexpected ';'  . Já revisei tudo e aparentemente a sintaxe está correta.

Comment: está faltando um ) antes do ;  altere para  fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data ));

Comment: Boa deu certo..Obrigado.